# Netrw doesn't recognize "~/"

Tags: netrw

I installed ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso on VirtualBox 6.1.28.  It is my first foray into virtual machines and Linux.

I installed Vim 8.1 according to [this page](https://superuser.com/a/332929).

The command `:e ~/tmp/tmp.txt` opens up `/tmp/tmp.txt` rather than the expected `~/tmp/tmp.txt`.  However, `:e ~MyUserName/tmp/tmp.txt` opens up `~MyUserName/tmp/tmp.txt` as expected.

Furthermore, for the `:e` command, whenever I specify a filepath starting with `~/`, (e.g., `~/` or `~/tmp`) the vim process is pushed to the background and I am brought to the bash prompt.  This happens immediately after I press `Return`.  Issuing `%%` puts me back into Vim, but I am the wrong folder.  For `:e ~/`, I am editing `/`, while for `:e ~/tmp`, I am editing `/tmp`.

I never saw `~` being ignored before, either on Solaris back in the day, nor in Cygwin in the past 1.5 decades.  Cygwin's Vim is no version 8.2.

**What can I do to have Netrw recognize `~`?**

Comment: That typically means the `$HOME` environment variable is not properly set... What does `:echo $HOME` tell you inside Vim? Or `echo $HOME` in your shell?

Comment: Though the "going to background" part is really odd... Does that happen right as you type the `~`, or when you press Enter at the end of the command? Can you try to check whether the same happens under `vim --clean`? Are you connecting to your VirtualBox via SSH or something, or using the VirtualBox console directly? Running a GUI environment such as GNOME on your Ubuntu VM?

Comment: @filbranden: Just before reading your comments, I found that `:echo $USERNAME` works, but `:echo "+".$HOME."+"` shows a zero-length string for `$HOME`. It is *not* empty if I run `vim -u NONE` or `vim --clean`.  I am currently trying to track down where `$HOME` gets clobbered in my ginormous `/etc/vim/vimrc`. A search for `HOME` identifies all locations, none of which would clobber `$HOME`. I'll clarify above exactly when Vim gets put into the background.

Comment: The problem was the vimscript `if has("win32unix") <code for Cygwin> else <code for Windows>`.  That worked when I only used Cygwin and Windows. Now I I run a Ubuntu VM, and this scenario falls through to `code for Windows`.  I had to change `else` to `elseif !has("unix")` to prevent this.  Worthwhile posting as an answer, or simply deleting the question?

Comment: I think you can also manually assign the variable in your .vimrc: `:let $HOME="/home/user"`

Comment: That's hard coding....something to do in the most dire of emergencies, but to be fixed immediately afterward. In the conditional setting of `$HOME` based on `!has("win32unix")`, it was necessary, but I still tried to avoid hard coding by using `$USERPROFILE."/Documents"`, i.e., the users `Document` folder on Windows.

Comment: Why was it necessary? I no longer use Gvim for Windows, so I can't be sure, but I keep the code around in case I have to use it one day. Speculating, Gvim for windows might inherit `$HOME` from the environment, and it might already default to `$USERPROFILE."/Documents"`. In the corporate Windows image I used, however, `$HOME` defaulted to a network drive, which I avoided because accessibility wasn't persistent. With my vimcode, I could use the same vimrc across administrator and non-administrator accounts. When I started to use Ubuntu, however, `$USERPROFILE` didn't exist.

Comment: @user2153235 Yes please go ahead and post it as an answer. Self-answers are totally encouraged, as they can be helpful and useful for others with similar problems (even if their issues are not exactly the same, your findings may help guide them to look for their particular issue.) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *filbranden* commented, the inability to recognize one's home directory `~/` is often due to an improperly set `$HOME` variable.  You can check this with `:echo $HOME`.

This next part is more specific to my situation.  One way that $HOME could be mis-set is if you have conditional *vimrc* code that customizes it based on the OS that vim is operating in.  I had code that sets it differently depending on whether I used Cygwin's Vim or Windows's Vim.  I recently moved to Ubuntu, and the *vimrc* logic wasn't properly coded to recognize this and act accordingly.  As coded, the logic caused the Windows code to run, which sets `$HOME` based on `$USERPROFILE`.  In Ubuntu, `$USERPROFILE` does not exist.  The vimcode resulted in $HOME being an empty string.